# Invalid option for dirname

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple script called abc.sh as follows, that sets the environment variables

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcePath () {
filename=`basename $0`

current_dir="./"$filename
if [ "$current_dir" = "$0" ]; then        SRC_DIR=$(pwd) 
         SRC_DIR=$(cd "$SRC_DIR/.."; pwd)
else        SRC_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."; pwd)
fi
}

sourcePath
echo $SRC_DIR
export SRC_DIR
```

I would like this script to set the variable SRC_DIR in my current shell environment. Hence, when i do source abc.sh, i get an error saying invalid options to dirname.
But if i run this file with ./abc.sh, i dont get any error, but then it wont export the variable

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is that $0 has a different value when you source the script, because sourcing is just the same as typing commands directly to the shell. So when you run the script, $0 is abc.sh, but when you source it, $0 is /bin/bash. You can see this by setting the -x flag:

```
set -x
source abc.sh
```

But I can't be sure that this is the only problem, because when I source the script I don't get an error from dirname, and the script prints "/".

Answer (score 0):

If you do `source`, then `$0` won't change (won't be the name of your executable, e.g.: `./abc.sh`).

Comment: i need to do source, so with source, is there a way to get the value ./abc.sh ?

Comment: `source ./abc.sh ./abc.sh` ? :) use a `function`? not sure what you want do, your script looks really messed...